# Less than or equal to symbol in RTF field

Tags: 2013, cme, rtf

I am trying to enter below text in a RTF field source view.

```
One is &le; One
One is &#8804; One
One is &#x2264; One
```

Post above entry, I am switching to design view where I am able to see the content as expected i.e.,

One is ≤ One

When I switch again back to source view of RTF field, the it is showing 
"One is ≤ One" instead of

```
One is &le; One
```

Any idea how I can persist

```
&le;
```

in source view of RTF field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you switch views, the data is loaded into an XML document in order to allow the format area XSLT to be executed. When this happens, the serialisation format is lost, and you have an in-memory representation of your characters. When the XSLT executes, the data from your XML document is again serialised, and in this case, you get a byte-representation of the character.

If this is desperately important to you, you might consider writing call templates in the XSLT to process element content and output the relevant sequences, but I'm left wondering what the point is. What is your reason for wanting to do this?